# OpenGL ES - GLSL returning calculations

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, shader, tracking

I'm trying to create a face tracker for iPhone using the GPU to perform calculations for performance.

To make the tracking more intelligent, I need to be able to retrieve values from the shader. 
However I'm having difficultly doing so, Is this possible with iPhone OpenGL ES?

Comment: As Christian pointed out, we need a lot more information about *what* information you need to retrieve in order to answer this.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get any output from shaders (at least in ES) is by rendering something to the framebuffer and reading back the resulting pixel values from the GPU.

But since I don't know your algorithm and implementation, I cannot tell you how best to structure it for getting results back efficiently. But just remember, the only output from shaders is the image rendered into the framebuffer, whatever structure this image may have.

Therefore it is usually best to structure your algorithms for minimal CPU-GPU communication. So think if you really need to know those values on the CPU or if it is enough to provide them to other parts of your GPU algorithm using textures or VBOs, into which you can render (more or less) efficiently without the need for CPU roundtrips.